# Liblinear bias very close to zero

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

I am trying out Liblinear for linear SVM classification on some 2D points (I am using a simple python gui to add points for 2 classes and then draw the line that separates the classes), but even though I am using the bias option (-B 1) for training, I get a bias very close to zero (the separating line almost passes through the origin).

I also tried simply training the 2-point set:

```
-1 1:10 2:30
+1 1:10 2:80
```

but I still get a very small bias (a line passing through the origin instead of a horizontal line in the XY plane as I guess it should be). Here is my output vector w:

```
0.2003362041634111, 
-0.03465897160331861, 
0.0200336204163411
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you are doing anything wrong.

From the liblinear FAQ:

> Q: Is LIBLINEAR gives the same result as LIBSVM with linear kernel?
>
> They should be very similar. However, sometimes the difference may not
> be small. Note that LIBLINEAR does not use the bias term b by default.
> If you observe very different results, try to set -B 1 for LIBLINEAR.
> This will add the bias term to the loss function as well as the
> regularization term (w^Tw + b^2). Then, results should be closer.

This says that liblinear tries to make the bias term as small as possible. If it can set it to zero and still get good training-set accuracy then it will.

There isn't a particularly good reason to imagine that regularising the bias will provide a better classifier, so many other learning systems it does not enter into the regularisation term. However in 'real-world' problems with very high dimensionality it's also very likely that the data are separable without needing a bias term, so regularising it does no harm and can be easier to implement.

Comment: I tried the library with high-dimensional data (I tried with some random N-dimensional points and now I'm using it for images) and it works much better indeed.